# Bash regex wildcard file pattern matching

Tags: bash, glob

I have a variable called `PARAM_COMPARE` which is set to `*.md`.

I'd like to compare filenames from GitHub Commits endpoint against `PARAM_COMPARE`.

```bash
gh api repos/"$PARAM_GH_PROJECT"/"$PARAM_GH_REPO"/commits/"$PARAM_GH_SHA" | jq -r '.files[].filename' | while read filename; do
  echo "${filename}" "${PARAM_COMPARE}"
  if [[ $filename =~ $PARAM_COMPARE ]]; then
    echo matched
    break
  fi
done
```

This sadly says it is not a match, even when the filename is `README.md`.

Have I forgotten something in this script?

Comment: You're mixing up shell patterns and regular expressions. Is this a good duplicate? [How to check if a file name matches regex in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37037767/3266847)

Comment: `*.md` is not a regex, it is a glob pattern. Use `[[ $filename = $PARAM_COMPARE ]]`

Comment: @anubhava Or better: use `case $filename in  $PARAM_COMPARE ) ... ;; esac`

Comment: Thank you @anubhava @Benjamin W. @F. Hauri.

I opted to change it to a blob pattern but also include another if block for regex matching.

`
  if [[ $filename =~ $PARAM_COMPARE ]]; then
    echo "matched regex"
    break
  fi

  # shellcheck disable=SC2053
  if [[ $filename == $PARAM_COMPARE ]]; then
    echo "matched glob"
    break
  fi
`

It's not the most elegant but I want to be able to cover whatever a user may pass to PARAM_COMPARE.